# OWASP ZAP - wrong NTLM challenge order - Out of sequence NTLM response message

Tags: security, ntlm, owasp, zap, penetration-tools

I need help with NTLM authentication configuration.

I am currently testing an AJAX web application using OWASP ZAP. The application is reachable via HTTPS and has NTLM auth enabled. When I run the scan, ZAP does not keep the proper sequence of NTLM negotiation.
**The expected way of NTLM connection is:**

1. Client sends GET to receive the website
2. Server sends WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate and WWW-Authenticate: NTLM with 401 code
3. Client sends auth information with Authorization:Negotiate
4. Server responds with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate and responds with requested page and code 200.

This scenario happens during the scan, but only first 2 steps - after receiving the Negotiate/NTLM challenge ZAP just starts the next test.
**Every few tests though, ZAP tries to perform the test by skipping step 3:**

1. ZAP sends Authorization:Negotiate with NTLM encoded with base64,
2. Server sends WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate and WWW-Authenticate: NTLM with 401 code

After that ZAP just skips the test and saves an entry in zap.log:

"2018-07-16 18:07:57,969 [ZAP-ActiveScanner-1] ERROR HttpMethodDirector - Out of sequence NTLM response message
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException: Out of sequence NTLM response message".

Do you know what could be the issue here? Below I send you what I did with configuration, what are my logging options and what errors did I receive.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

1. Open the web browser with proxy configured for ZAP and click through the whole web application on https://example.com:9443/service (it's an AJAX service). I did not use an AJAX spider cause it often does not provide valid input on data-validated inputs.
2. Sessions properties: Create new context with https://example.com:9443/service.*
3. Sessions properties: Authentication: HTTP/NTLM Authentication

Hostname: https://example.com

Port: 8443

Realm: left empty (tried also with {AD Domain} and {AD Domain}.local)

Regex pattern identified in Logged In response: {string_from_logged_in_response}

3. Sessions properties: Users: Add a valid user from the domain (tried both "{username}" and "{AD Domain}{username}")

4.Forced User: username set in step 3

5. Session management: HTTP Authentication Session Management
6. Authorization: HTTP Status Code: 401

Body contains regex: 'access restricted' (string that is placed on 401 page of the webapp). At least one of the conditions above must match.

**After configuration run the scan:**

7. On the Sites tree, right click on https://example.com:9443/service -> Attack -> Active Scan
8. In the Active Scan Scope tab:

Starting point: https://example.com:9443/service

Policy: Default

Context: The one configured above (step 1)

User: The one configured above (step 3)

9. Start scan.

**Logs I encounter - there is also one error with parsing the request body:**

```
2018-07-16 18:07:57,414 [Thread-607] INFO HostProcess - Scanning 90 node(s) from https://example.com:9443/service as {user}
2018-07-16 18:07:57,418 [Thread-607] INFO HostProcess - start host https://example.com:9443/service | TestRemoteFileInclude strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
2018-07-16 18:07:57,442 [Thread-607] ERROR HttpMethodDirector - Out of sequence NTLM response message
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException: Out of sequence NTLM response message
at org.zaproxy.zap.network.ZapNTLMScheme.processChallenge(ZapNTLMScheme.java:131)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor.processChallenge(AuthChallengeProcessor.java:162)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processWWWAuthChallenge(HttpMethodDirector.java:773)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processAuthenticationResponse(HttpMethodDirector.java:747)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:221)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(HttpSender.java:333)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(HttpSender.java:562)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:523)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:501)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:490)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:405)
at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:362)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess.obtainResponse(HostProcess.java:507)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess.scanMessage(HostProcess.java:460)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess.processPlugin(HostProcess.java:371)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess.run(HostProcess.java:302)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-07-16 18:50:03,583 [ZAP-ActiveScanner-0] WARN VariantJSONQuery - Failed to parse the request body: Input is invalid JSON; does not start with '{' or '[', c=-1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input is invalid JSON; does not start with '{' or '[', c=-1
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.VariantJSONQuery.parseObject(VariantJSONQuery.java:117)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.VariantJSONQuery.parseContent(VariantJSONQuery.java:61)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.VariantAbstractRPCQuery.setRequestContent(VariantAbstractRPCQuery.java:167)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.VariantAbstractRPCQuery.setMessage(VariantAbstractRPCQuery.java:51)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractAppParamPlugin.scan(AbstractAppParamPlugin.java:161)
at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.AbstractPlugin.run(AbstractPlugin.java:380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Logging settings:**

```
log4j.logger.org.parosproxy.paros=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.zaproxy.zap=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.htmlparser.jericho=ERROR
```

**Installation configuration:**

```
ZAP: 2.7.0
Add-on: Set of default Add-ons. 
OS: Windows 10 17134
Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Browser: clicking through the application was done with Chrome, version 67.0.3396.99
```

Comment: This has been raised as a ZAP issue: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4847

Comment: Yes, I raised it as an issue actually. I decided to ask on stackoverflow as well as I am not sure if it is misconfiguration - I tried many different combinations of configuration with similar effects though.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and I detect the same behavior. I suspect this might be a newer version of IIS (10) working with some older NTML library.

Comment: I am not sure if it is IIS which should respond instantly to NTLM Negotiate (without initial GET nad server call for authentication) or if it is ZAP issue. The communication order is completely different when using browser and when trying to log in through ZAP.